# Apache Rewrite URL for parameters in .htaccess File

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal is:

`domain.com/add/10/aname` => `domain.com?action=add&id=10&name=aname`

here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ ./index.php?&action=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [L,NC]
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading slash is not matched in .htaccess and better to avoid using `.*`

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?&action=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]
```